# Do flaming weapons with the trip special weapon feature deal their extra damage on trip attempts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, trip

Do flaming (and other elemental damage) weapons that have the [trip special weapon feature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Trip) deal their extra damage when they are used in a trip attack and hit successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they do not.

The fire (or other elemental) damage dealt by such weapons is *extra* damage, by definition added to whatever damage the weapon deals under other circumstances. A trip maneuver does not deal damage, and thus does not deal the extra damage either.

This is made explicit under [Actions in Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat):

> options that increase damage don't cause attacks to deal damage if they wouldn't otherwise do so (such as Vital Strike and trip)