# Does a Rust Monster's Rust (Su) apply to other kinds of touch attacks it makes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, touch-attacks, combat-maneuver

I have a rust monster with the Greater Trip and Fury's Fall feats and the ability to cast a handful of spells, which opens up some situations I've not seen before.

If I make a trip attempt with a [rust monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/rust-monster)'s antennae, and my foe is in a heavy armor that covers their feet, do I get the benefit of the rust ability as well as the trip?

Can a rust monster deliver a touch attack with their antennae and get the rust ability on top of the touch spell?  (Even if the spell is *rusting grasp*?)

Rather than sundering with the antennae, could I attempt a disarm and still rust the weapon if successful, in addition to flinging it to the ground?

Comment: Is this rust monster improved somehow? (The stock rust monster's Combat Maneuver Bonus is *terrible*. Also, a link to the 3rd-party class—even if the link only points to where to buy the PDF—would be useful.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan oddly enough, the rust monster link presently leads to a page with an ad for Mystical: Kingdom of Monsters, which is where the class comes from.  (I'm hunting my old questions I haven't accepted answers on, to try to clean those up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** You use the rust monster's Rust(Su) ability as a standard action in the form of a melee touch attack. When you make the combat maneuver, you *replace* your attack with the combat maneuver.

> If I make a trip attempt with a rust monster's antennae, and my foe is in a heavy armor that covers their feet, do I get the benefit of the rust ability as well as the trip?

No, the rust monsters Rust(SU) only applies to the antennae attack. When you make an attack roll, you may "*substitute*" it for a combat maneuver. The only time you specify what you are performing the combat maneuver with is in scenarios like disarm, where wielding a weapon grants you a bonus / not wielding a weapon allows you to take the weapon if you succeed at a penalty to the maneuver.

> Can a rust monster deliver a touch attack with their antennae and get the rust ability on top of the touch spell? (Even if the spell is rusting grasp?)

Yes. You would use the antennae combat bonus and risk losing the spell like you would under normal circumstances.

> Rather than sundering with the antennae, could I attempt a disarm and still rust the weapon if successful, in addition to flinging it to the ground?

No, for the same reason as the first question. If the rust monster was capable of performing combat maneuvers with it's antennae then it would have been mentioned in the monsters stat block. If you continue reading I go into more explanation about SU abilities and standard actions, if the Rust(su) ability specifically stated that it was not a standard action to perform then there would be a possibility.

**Resources:**

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Standard-Action
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-

Lets start with the standard actions: Supernatural Abilities (su) is usually a standard action unless otherwise defined by the ability's description. Under the Rust(SU) description found under the rust monster character sheet: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/rust-monster it says it is a touch attack and it does not mention it being any other form of action = it is a standard action to perform. You cannot perform two standard actions normally in a round so in order for you to trip (a standard action) and use your Rust (su) (with your antennae : another standard action) you would have to use a full-round action and replace one of your attacks with a trip and one with the Rust (su).

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuvers

Any combination of a creature's attacks during a melle full attack can be replaced by a trip, disarm, or sunder maneuver. (any maneuver that says "*in pace of a melee attack*"). when doing this, the calculation for the creature's CMB uses base attack bonus of the attack that was exchanged for a combat maneuver.

If we continue to the trip section you will see a note about how making trip attempts do not require a weapon with a "*trip*" special feature. You can use any weapon for example, a longsword or an unarmed strike, the only advantage for using a weapon with a "*trip*" special feature is so that if your combat maneuver fails by 10 or more you can drop the trip weapon instead of falling prone yourself.

If you were curious if combat maneuvers did damage they do not: You can find numerous questions and resources online where people ask the same question and in the end: trips are done in place of an attack, the result is knocking your opponent prone not dealing damage normally.

Here is another similar source: [Do flaming weapons with the trip special weapon feature deal their extra damage on trip attempts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62997/do-flaming-weapons-with-the-trip-special-weapon-feature-deal-their-extra-damage) You are simply substituting the flaming extra damage for the Rust (SU)

**Touch Spells**

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Spells-in-Combat

> If you don't discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell, you can hold the charge indefinitely. You can continue to make touch attacks round after round. If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges.

The entire section about "*Holding the Charge*" Was what I was referring to OP

Comment: The third-party class doesn't matter in the slightest.  The same questions would apply to a GM using an advanced rust monster or just a rust monster with a customized feat selection.  This answer would benefit from rules citations (and when do you risk losing a touch spell in your second section?).

Comment: @gatherer818 Answer has been updated, let me know if you need anything else clarified.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can't even use the antennae attack as part of a full attack action then, even though its listed as a separate attack from the bite?  I can *only* use the antennae attack as a standard action?

Comment: @gatherer818 No, and how are you reading this? http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions An attack is a standard action, if your character has multiple attacks you can then decide after the first attack (provided you didn't move or expend any other action) to use your other attacks

Comment: @gatherer818 A rust monster typically has two attack methods: the bite, and the antennae: You attack with your bite and then you have the option to either use a move action, or as a full round action use your antennae. You can use them in any order you wish (you can start with the antennae, w/e), when you wish to make a combat maneuver you then *replace* your attack (ie: the bite or the antennae) with the combat maneuver.